# which version of firefox do we need for Selenium 3.3.1?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, gecko, selenium-firefoxdriver

which version of firefox do we need for Selenium 3.3.1?? I'm trying to use firefox 51 with selenium 3.3.1 and I'm not able to launch the application please let me know which browser do we need to use for selenium 3.3.1

Comment: Are you using latest version of gecko driver? https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: yes gecko driver v15

Comment: Can you update the Firefox to 52 and place the instantiation code you are using and there is no know issue in which you cannot  launch firefox with 3.3.1 if you are using latest geckodriver

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 51/52 works well with GeckoDriver 0.15.0 and Selenium 3.3.1. You would need to download correct version of GeckoDriver based on whether Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit in Windows. Also, you may need to provide Firefox Binary which can be done with `FirefoxOptions` class.

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Refer this article for more details - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Answer (score 0):

To quote the team of geckodriver:

> Support is best in Firefox 48 and onwards, although generally the more
>   recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as they have
>   more bug fixes and features. We strongly advise using the latest
>   Firefox Nightly with geckodriver, and want to make it clear that
>   Firefox 47 and earlier is explicitly not supported. Since Windows XP
>   support in Firefox will be dropped with Firefox 53, we do not support
>   this platform.

see also: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows 32 bit machine.

Selenium WebDriver - 3.4.0, Selenium.Support - 3.4.0

Firefox - 54.0 (32 bit)

GeckoDriver (32 bit) downloaded and stored locally - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Firefox installed and it's 'firefox.exe' path is provided.

**Code to launch Firefox Browser below:**

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\GeckoDriver");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```